# Few includes in the same space

Tags: android, android-layout

As you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGrlH.png), the **profile_content** Layout takes the whole space available and when I press the "Profile" button the information display correctly.

But when I press the "Messages" button it's not display anything. As you can se in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbAnB.png), the "blue rectangle" does not fill the whole space like the profile_content Layout.

Both layouts have the same value (wrap_content) in **android:layout_widt** parameter.

I have some code like:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bProfile:
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick, buttonProfile pressed");
                //Hide previous layout
                activeLayout = "bProfile";
                profileContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Access for extras passed in from login activity
                tUserName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("tProfileName"));
                break;
            case R.id.bMessages:
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick, buttonMessages pressed");
                profileContent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                messagesContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                activeLayout = "bMessages";
                test.setText("Test");
                break;

        }
    }
```

Maybe I should use FragmentLayout for this particular functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout isn't gonna help you in this situation. Try using RelativeLayout, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="QWERTY" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="QWERTY" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ASDFG" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonsMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/profile_content"
            layout="@layout/profile_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/profile_content"
            layout="@layout/messages_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```